# fgetc always return -1

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to read one character at time from a text file but fgetc is returning -1 from start, which mean inside of loop is never entered. fileSize is 11 under run-time and no errors is displayed.

//main.c

```
char *buffer = NULL;

char* readFile(const char *path) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(path, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        perror(path);
        printf("Error: %d \n", errno);
        return "Error";
    }


    //get size of file.
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t fileSize = ftell(file); 

    //allocate sizeof file +1.
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc((fileSize +1) * sizeof(char));

    //read file into string
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        buffer[i] = (char)c;
        ++i;
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0';

    fclose(file);

return buffer;
}

void freeMem(void) {
    free(buffer);
}
int main(void) {
    const char *path = "C:\\Programmering\\TestReader\\syntax\\file.txt";
    char *cStr = readFile(path);

    //freeMem();
    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

//file.txt

Hello World

Comment: Try `rewind` or `fseek` to reposition after using `ftell`.

Comment: Thanks it works but why and how?

Comment: Do not ad unrelated tags! C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: Due to fseek position may have been set to last ,therefore.

Answer (score 0):

your read loop is located after your:
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
statement!!!

you are at the end of file when you call your fgetc function!

perhaps you can add fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); after the ftell call?

Comment: Thanks for fast response this solution works. Unfortunaly i dont have enough reputation to upvote your response...